# What is the principal part of the Laurent series expansion of $f(z)= \frac{2}{z^5 (1-2z)}$ at the origin?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

What is the principal part of the Laurent series expansion of $f(z)= \frac{2}{z^5 (1-2z)}$ at the origin?

Attempt: Rewrite the function as $\frac{2}{z^5}\cdot \frac{1}{1-2z}$. The Laurent series expansion of $\frac{1}{1-2z}$ is given by:

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1-2z} &= 1 + 2z + 4z^2 + 8z^3 + \ldots \
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^n z^n
\end{align*}

So the Laurent series expansion of $f(z)$ is:

$$f(z) = \frac{2}{z^5}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^n z^n\right) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{n+1} z^{n-5}$$

Hence, principal part is

$$2 z^{-5} + 4 z^{-4} + 8 z^{-3} + 16 z^{-2} + 32 z^{-1}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: `Series[2/(z^5*(1 - 2 z)), {z, 0, 2}]` $\frac{2}{z^5}+\frac{4}{z^4}+\frac{8}{z^3}+\frac{16}{z^2}+\frac{32}{z}+64+128 z+256 z^2+O\left(z^3\right)$  yes,that's correct

Comment: The region of convergence of $
\frac{1}{1-2z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^n z^n$ is $|z| \leq 1/2$. Is this also the region of convergence of $\frac{2}{z^5} \cdot \frac{1}{1-2z}$?

Comment: The region of convergence should be the punctured disk $0\lt\lvert z\rvert \lt\dfrac 12$.